# DDEV Connect to MySQL Database from Staging Server by SSH Tunnel returns: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: mysql, ssh, typo3, tunnel, ddev

I am developing a TYPO3 project locally in a DDEV environment. All developers want to access the same MySQL database. We want to achieve this via SSH tunnel to the staging server. Unfortunately I don't manage to establish a SSH tunnel to the database from DDEV.

What do I do?

```
ddev exec ssh -v -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 customer@stage.customer.tld
```

Error that occurs:

```
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 3306.
bind [::1]:3306: Cannot assign requested address
```

Also with other ports, always the same error. What do I have to set in DDEV to make this work?

Thanks for your support!

Comment: Sharing a database is an unusual thing to do, unless you just have a huge set of read-only data.  But first, experiment inside the web container, don't use `ddev exec`. Why are you trying to use a tunnel instead of directly accessing the database by hostname? And please note that the *ddev* db server is not in the webserver, so wouldn't be on 127.0.0.1 anyway.  If you can say why you're trying to use a tunnel it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

All i have to do was switching to a free port, in my case: 3308

So this code is working fine:

```
ddev exec ssh -v -4 -L 3308:127.0.0.1:3306 customer@stage.customer.tld
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As in the comment above, there's no reason I know of to use a tunnel instead of direct access to the target server.

But if you must, the answer is in https://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2014/09/24/ssh-port-forwarding-bind-cannot-assign-requested-address/ - you need to use `ssh -4 -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 customer@stage.customer.tld`

Please note that in ddev the mariadb/mysql server is not running inside the web container, it's a separate container, so putting your tunnel on 3306 in the web container is probably a mistake anyway. Besides not needing a tunnel.

Also, sshd (on your server) does not by default allow this kind of tunneling, you have to enable AllowTcpForwarding on the server.

Comment: I thought the way over the SSH tunnel, makes the connection significantly more tap-proof compared to a direct connection. In terms of data protection, I found the way therefore smarter.

Unfortunately the connection with "-4" which forces IPv4 still does not work :-(

Good hint that Web and DB are two sepparate containers. In the end I don't care about the internal DDEV database, I just want to work with the externally connected database.

Comment: Using an ssh tunnel encrypts the connection. But mysql has the capability of using an encrypted connection as well; however I haven't ever used that.  You don't say what "still does not work" means - I am certain you have different results. The way to experiment with tunnels is to establish them manually and test them. There are lots of internet resources, but it's kind of tricky. One key reason you might be having trouble is that the server must have AllowTcpForwarding set in its sshd_config, which is not the default.